# Async callback from Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that may receive messages from an external system (UDP/TCP). Based on the content of the incoming data, there are cases when I want the actor to call back to a non-aka part of my code.
In other words, I don't want to call and actor with `ask` and wait for some incoming data but rather be called back asynchronously.
How can I implement this without e.g. closing over the calling object (the trivial would be pass in a callback on creation of ActorRef but this would capture caller)?

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? I am confused about who is calling back and who is being called back. `ask` is asynchronous (it returns a `Future`) so it is not clear why this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a functional interface `handleMessage` - that is, a method `handleMessage` that only accepts immutable data - you can simply wrap it in a `Future`, run inside the actor's context:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

// Inside your actor, this is the implicit execution context holding the thread
// pool the actor executes within. You MUST import this in order for it to be in
// the implicit scope for scala.concurrent.Future.
import context.dispatcher
Future {
  handleMessage(messageData)
  // If you need to know when this completes, send a message to the initiating
  // actor here.
}
```